# Are Service Workers available on Firefox for iOS?

Tags: ios, firefox, service-worker

I'm trying to create a HTML5 app for mobiles and I need offline capabilities.
My idea was to use Firefox for it is available on lot of phones.
But, since Firefox for iOS is relatively recent, I wonder if it supports Service Workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm serving [UpUp](https://www.talater.com/upup/) from a http://surge.sh subdomain and it's not working in Firefox iOS 2.1 (4).

Comment: Ok. So I have to wait before using this through every platform. Thanks.